# How to force typescript to capture "this"?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a following:

```
module Test {
    export class Foo {
        public A = 123;
        public GetA() {
            return this.A;
        }
    }
}
```

which compiles to

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    var Foo = (function () {
        function Foo() {
            this.A = 123;
        }
        Foo.prototype.GetA = function () {
            return this.A;
        };
        return Foo;
    })();
    Test.Foo = Foo;
})(Test || (Test = {}));
```

And its all great, but I have a case when GetA will be run in a context of different object, so I need to capture 'this' in a closure.

So basically I need to have this JS:

```
function Foo() {
    this.A = 123;
    var self = this;
    this.GetA = function () {
        return self.A;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get this with class semantics of typescript, of should I just fallback to plain JS?

Comment: How are you executing `GetA` in the context of a different object?

Comment: Mostly when you provide the function as callback (e.g. promise callback, event etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module Test {
    export class Foo {
        public A = 123;
        public GetA = ()=>{return this.A;}
    }
}
```

Please give it a try. This is the javascript generated:

```
        var Test;
        (function (Test) {
            var Foo = (function () {
                function Foo() {
                    var _this = this;
                    this.A = 123;
                    this.GetA = function () {
                        return _this.A;
                    };
                }
                return Foo;
            })();
            Test.Foo = Foo;
        })(Test || (Test = {}));
```

Comment: The function is no longer on the `prototype`, which may make this solution less desirable.

Comment: Do you really need it to be a prototype, the expected javascript is pretty much the same as generated one.

Comment: Without prototype super.GetA will not work. Would be useful to mention as WiredPrairie suggested

Answer (score 2):

For those who encounter this page, apparently TypeScript people adressed this here:
[https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript)