# TypeScript : How to capture 'this' when I'm using a class method?

Tags: class, asynchronous, methods, lambda, typescript

I'm trying to capture `this` when I'm using a class method in TypeScript.

```
/// <reference path="./typings/async/async.d.ts"/>

import async = require('async');

class Person {
  greet(callback) {
    if (!this.name) { return callback('name is not defined'); }
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name + '!');
    return callback();
  };
  constructor(public name: string) { };
}

var person1 = new Person('John');
var person2 = new Person('Jane');

console.log('Greet one person:');
person1.greet((err) => {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  return console.log('greeting is done\n');
});

console.log('Greet all peoples:');
async.series([person1.greet, person2.greet], (err) => {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  return console.log('greetings are done\n');
});
```

Output :

```
Greet one person:
Hello John!
greeting is done

Greet all peoples:
name is not defined
```

When I'm using the `greet` method as a [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) task, the context is no longer the `Person` instance.

I found a solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206887/how-to-force-typescript-to-capture-this). I can turn the `greet` method to a public member and use a [lambda function](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-lambdas-and-using-39this39).

```
greet = (callback) => {
  if (!this.name) { return callback('name is not defined'); }
  console.log('Hello ' + this.name + '!');
  return callback();
};
```

Output:

```
Greet one person:
Hello John!
greeting is done

Greet all peoples:
Hello John!
Hello Jane!
greetings are done
```

The problem is `greet` is not longer a part of the `Person` prototype but a member of the instance.

Does somebody have a solution to keep `greet` as a part of `Person` prototype ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to specify a context:

```
async.series([person1.greet.bind(person1), person2.greet.bind(person2)], ...);
```

Comment: This solution works but the syntax isn't very DRY. Is it impossible to encapsulate the logic in the class definition ?

Answer (score 1):

> greet as a part of Person prototype

No. This is because `prototype` is *shared* by all instances. Since there is only *one* it cannot be bound to a single instance without corrupting it for other instances.

Use an arrow function to bind it to `this` instead to let the compiler bind it per instance, or just use `bind` to create a *copy* of the function bound a specific instance.